# How to add image in background dynamically?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have one ScrollView on activity. Inside of this ScrollView there is one RelativeLayout. On layout I have several buttons which can expand layout and scrollView. Also, I want to set some image as background of this layout. But I have some problem: my layout can expand and image will resize. It's incorrect.
How can I decide this problem?

And can I make 'auto-loaded' background of layout? It means that if layout expands then below first image second image adds on background.

I have idea: maybe add view behind layout with background and change it when scroll view change position? It's good way or not?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`ViewStub`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewStub.html)

> A ViewStub is an invisible, zero-sized View that can be used to lazily inflate layout resources at runtime. When a ViewStub is made visible, or when inflate() is invoked, the layout resource is inflated. The ViewStub then replaces itself in its parent with the inflated View or Views.

[Example](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/loading-ondemand.html) from developer docs.